# How do I email my professor about assigning me to a group?

Tags: email, communication, international-students

I have a class project coming up, the professor asked us to form groups of 6. Everyone in class seems to know each other and have already started forming groups. Unfortunately, I don’t know anyone in that class. I would like to know how can I email my professor about assigning me to a group? I am an international student so I am not really sure how to address this.

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple:

> Dear Prof. X,
>
> I'm Hannah Y (ID n. 12345), an international student in your class
>   XYZ. Since I don't know anyone in the class, could you please assign 
>   me to one of the project groups?
>
> Thank you,
>
> Hannah

I have international students in my classes and such emails are not uncommon. The important thing is to provide all the pieces of information needed to identify you and the course (professors usually have several).

Comment: This is the main issue we had and we now have a « random » choice system - all the names are put in a box and groups of 5 or 6 pulled out - depending on the nunber we may have to do a few groups of 4 that get completed late. But, this has reduced the number of later group changes that we need to deal with : many times a group of friends start a project and, at the end, are no longer all friends : lack of input, too much time with a partner etc.

Comment: While I agree about including identifying information, I've had students going to the other extreme. One was so thorough about identifying themselves that even the lecturers for other subjects knew who they were.

Answer (score -5):

> how can I email my professor about assigning me to a group?

Don't seek complicated solutions for a simple problem.

1. Find the professor's e-mail address online.
2. Open your e-mail client and write the letter to him/her along the following lines: "Dear Prof. XXX,  I could not get into a group myself; please assign me to a group. Sincerely yours, Hannah ____"
3. Press the "send" button.

Comment: A repeat of the prior existing answer that adds nothing of note.